# Pipe and regex bash ouput

Tags: macos, bash, ffmpeg, terminal, zsh

I'm trying to get the dimensions of a video with ffmpeg. I use the command `ffprobe video.mov` to get the following data:

```
ffprobe version 1.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 14 2013 10:18:07 with Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.0 --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --cc=cc --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
  libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
  libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
  libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
  libavfilter     3. 17.100 /  3. 17.100
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'linebubble.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2013-03-12 02:59:34
  Duration: 00:00:14.05, start: 0.050000, bitrate: 135 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 502x288 [SAR 1:1 DAR 251:144], 137 kb/s, 7.84 fps, 60 tbr, 6k tbn, 12k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-12 02:59:34
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
```

Now I want to pipe that into a regex to just get  **502x288** on the fourth last line.

I've seen some solutions with python and perl, but I want this to be in plain bash. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it 2 dozen ways.  Here's a away using `grep` and `awk`:

```
ffprobe video.mov 2>&1 | grep 'Stream #0' | awk '{print $10}'
```

Comment: `grep | awk` is a useless use of grep. Better use `awk '/Stream/{print $10}'`

Comment: @Wes Interesting; `ffprobe` must be writing to `stderr` rather than `stdout`.  Try: `ffprobe video.mov 2>&1 | grep ...`.

Comment: @sputnick Ack is much slower than grep for matching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$ ffprobe video.mov 2>&1 | grep -oP '^\s+Stream.*?,\s+\K\d{2,}x\d{2,}' 
502x288
```

If you don't have `grep -oP` switchs :

```
$ ffprobe video.mov 2>&1 |
    perl -lne 'print $& if /^\s+Stream.*?,\s+\K\d{2,}x\d{2,}/'
502x288
```

This solution is not based of the Nth column, I think it's more reliable to search a comma followed by a space followed by 2 integers of at least 2 digits separated by `x`

Comment: Hrm, seems both of these still give me all the info from `ffprobe` in the termina. Am I piping properly? It appends grep usage to the top of everything